# How to perform arithmetic operation between the objects written in a file?

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

In my program, users enter values and those get stored in arrayList. ArryList objects are written into a file. I have used file-i/o, object-i/o stream for writing and readin in file.Now I want to perform addition and subtraction among the objects (`int or double`). That is withdrawing money from one account should be added with another account, and their value must be subtracted and added with the particular acount's amount. And finally I want that value must be updated so that it can print out and show the current status. How could I do that?

This is the main class:

```
public class BankApp_Assignment {

    //static int numOfAcc = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n");

        List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        List<BankAccount> bankAccounts2 = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        ReaderWriter rw=new ReaderWriter();


        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose your option:\n"
                    + "1. Create new account\n"
                    + "2. Deposit/withdraw\n"
                    + "3. View One account\n"
                    + "4. Deleting an account\n"
                    + "5. View all the accounts\n"
                    + "6. Return to menu\n");

            System.out.println("*************\n"
                    + "************");

            option1 = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            //switch-case starts
            switch (option1) {
                case 1:
                    //create account
                    BankAccount bankAcc = new BankAccount();
                    System.out.println("Enter Full Name:");
                    bankAcc.setName(sc.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("Choose an Account Number:");
                    bankAcc.setAccNum(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Choose the initial amount:");
                    bankAcc.setInitiateAmount(sc.nextDouble());
                    //adding those into the arrayList
                    bankAccounts.add(bankAcc);
                    rw.writeToFile(bankAccounts);

                    System.out.println("-------------\n"
                            + "-------------");
                    break;
                case 2:
                     bankAccounts2=(List<BankAccount>)rw.readFromFile();
                    //First displaying the current accouns info
                    System.out.println("Name \tAccount No \tInitial Amount");
                    for (BankAccount bankAccount : bankAccounts2) {

                        System.out.println(bankAccount);

                    }

                    System.out.println("\t\t.........\n"
                            + "\t\t.........");

                    System.out.println("To transfer money within the bank accounts enter 1\n"
                            + "To deposit/withdraw money in the same account enter 2");
                    option2 = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();

                    //inner switch-case starts
                    switch (option2) {
                        case 1:
                            /*
                            BankAccount is the class for setter and getter
                             bankAccounts2 is the arrayList for reading objects from file
                            */
                            bankAccounts2 = (List<BankAccount>) rw.readFromFile();
                            BankAccount fromAcc = null;
                            BankAccount toAcc = null;
                            System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to withdraw from:");

                            withdraw_accNum = sc.nextInt();

                            System.out.println("Enter the amount you want to withdraw:");

                            withdraw_amount = sc.nextDouble();
                            System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to deposit to:");

                            deposit_accNum = sc.nextInt();//the deposit amount is alwyas the same as withdraw_amount

                            //find the matching acc number:withdraw_accNum
                            for (BankAccount listItemsFirst : bankAccounts2) {
                                //if the withdraw acc num matches with the given one
                                if (listItemsFirst.getAccNum() == withdraw_accNum) {
                                    //store it
                                    fromAcc = listItemsFirst;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            //find the matching acc number:  deposit_accNum
                            for (BankAccount listItemsSec : bankAccounts2) {
                                //if the withdraw acc num matches with the given one
                                if (listItemsSec.getAccNum() == deposit_accNum) {
                                    //store it
                                    toAcc = listItemsSec;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            //if the withdraw amount is bigger than the current balance
                            if (withdraw_amount > fromAcc.getInitialAmount()) {
                                System.out.println("Withdrawing Amount was bigger than the Initial amount.\nChoose the menu again. .");
                                break;
                            }
                            //subtracting and adding the withdrawn amount
                            fromAcc.setInitiateAmount(fromAcc.getInitialAmount() - withdraw_amount);
                            toAcc.setInitiateAmount(toAcc.getInitialAmount() + withdraw_amount);
                            System.out.println("DONE!\t print them out to see the current status.");
                            System.out.println("");

                            break;
                        case 2://deposit/withdraw money in the same accounts
                            bankAccounts2=(List<BankAccount>)rw.readFromFile();
                            BankAccount fromAcc_SameAcc = null;
                            BankAccount toAcc_SameAcc = null;
                            System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to deposit or withdraw from:");
                            //read the accNum
                            depOrWithAccountNum = sc.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter the amount (To withdraw enter a negative value)");
                            //read the amount
                            depOrWithAmount = sc.nextDouble();
                            //checking the matching account number in arrayList
                            for (BankAccount listItemsThird : bankAccounts2) {
                                if (listItemsThird.getAccNum() == depOrWithAccountNum) {
                                    fromAcc_SameAcc = listItemsThird;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (depOrWithAmount - 1 < fromAcc_SameAcc.getInitialAmount()) {
                                System.out.println("Withdraw amount is bigger than the current amount.\nChoose the menu again. .");
                                break;
                            }

                            if (depOrWithAmount < 0) {//the amount is negative
                                fromAcc_SameAcc.setInitiateAmount(fromAcc_SameAcc.getInitialAmount() + depOrWithAmount);
                            } else {
                                fromAcc_SameAcc.setInitiateAmount(fromAcc_SameAcc.getInitialAmount() + depOrWithAmount);
                            }

                            break;
                    }

                    //inner switch-case ends
                    System.out.println("\n\n");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    //View One account
                    bankAccounts2=(List<BankAccount>)rw.readFromFile();
                    BankAccount viewOneAccountNum = null;

                    System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to see:");
                    viewOneAcc = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Name\tAccount No\tInitial Amount");
                    for (BankAccount viewOneAccountProperty : bankAccounts2) {

                        if (viewOneAccountProperty.getAccNum() == viewOneAcc) {
                            //viewOneAccountNum=viewOneAccountProperty;
                            viewOneAccountNum = viewOneAccountProperty;

                            System.out.println(viewOneAccountNum);
                        }
                        System.out.println("");

                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                     bankAccounts2=(List<BankAccount>)rw.readFromFile();
                    //BankAccount AccToDel = null;
                    //Deleting an account
                    Iterator<BankAccount> it = bankAccounts2.iterator();

                    System.out.println("Enter the account you want to delete:");
                    deleteAcc = sc.nextInt();

                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        BankAccount next = it.next();
                        if (next.getAccNum() == deleteAcc) {
                            it.remove();
                        }
                    }

                    rw.writeToFile(bankAccounts2);


                    break;

                case 5:
                    //View all the accounts/printing them out

                    bankAccounts2=(List<BankAccount>)rw.readFromFile();
                    System.out.println("Name\tAccount No\tInitial Amount");
                    for (BankAccount bankAccount : bankAccounts2) {

                        System.out.println(bankAccount);

                    }

                    System.out.println("\n\n");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    //Quit
                    return;
            }

            //switch-case ends
        }

    }

}
```

ReaderWriter:

```
public class ReaderWriter{
 public void writeToFile(List<BankAccount> accounts){
   try {
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile_assignment.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(accounts);//take the arrayList 
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public  List<BankAccount> readFromFile(){
        List<BankAccount>readData=null;
        try {



            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankFile_assignment.txt");
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            //make an arrayList to get those object back
            //arrayList

            readData=(List<BankAccount>)ois.readObject();

         ois.close();
         fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return readData;
        return readData;


    }
}
```

BankAccount:

```
    package bankapp_assignment;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class BankAccount implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    private int accNum;
    private double initiateAmount;

    //constructor
    public BankAccount() {

        this.name = null;
        this.accNum = 0;
        this.initiateAmount = 0;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public void setAccNum(int accNum) {

        this.accNum = accNum;
    }

    public String getName(String name){
        return name;

    }


    public int getAccNum() {
        return accNum;
    }


    public void setInitiateAmount(double initiateAmount) {
        this.initiateAmount = initiateAmount;
    }

    public double getInitialAmount(){
        return initiateAmount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "\t\t" + accNum + "\t\t" + initiateAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: it depends how text in files is formatted, could you post a example tof file content?

Comment: m.cekiera, yes please, I have updated my post. I will be greatful if I get some help.

Comment: I ment .txt file content, to show how you store data, to know how to retrive it ;)

Comment: m.cekiera, I have posted my whole main class. That describes the contents of the file. I haven't posted the class for getter and setter, but if u want I can do it.  Please.

Comment: What is BankAccount? how it store data?

Comment: m.cekiera, its also updated.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should refactor whole main method. If I were you, I would use
   main only to lunch program, rest process in other methods. This way you would be able to use class fields all over program, and divide code into many methods.
2. You should divide main beetween other methods, to at least method
   per action, exemple:

   ```
   case 1:
       createAccount();
       break;
   (...) 
   public void createAccount(){
   code from your swich case 1
   }
   ```

   etc. You can still use swich control, but should replece logic code to another method.
3. When i run your code, input/output didn't work. Were you able to
       save/load file? I had to chage:

   ```
   File file = new File("//file path");
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
   ObjectOutput oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   ```

   Same with input. Then it worked.
4. Now, we will try to deal with operation on BankAccounts from files. I change a little bit your code from case2/case2: deposit/withdraw, lets look at it:

   ```
   bankAccounts2 = rw.readFromFile();               // loading list from file
   BankAccount edited = new BankAccount();          // creating new object
   System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to deposit or withdraw from:");
   double input = sc.nextInt();                     // you don't need to create new variable every time you take input form user
   for(BankAccount account : bankAccounts2){        // every account in list
          if(account.getAccNum() == input) edited = account;  // if acccNum match, give edited reference to chosen account
   }
   System.out.println("Enter the amount (To withdraw enter a negative value)");
   input = sc.nextDouble();

   double result = edited.getInitialAmount() + input;  // result of operation
   if(result < 0){   // check if there is enough money on account
       System.out.println("Withdraw amount is bigger than the current amount.\nChoose the menu again. .");
       break;
   }else{
       edited.setInitiateAmount(result);               // if there is, set new value
   }
   rw.writeToFile(bankAccounts2);                      // save file
   ```

You can implement another operation in similar style. But still, you should consider dividing main into other methods, adding class fields, etc.

EDIT:

For question in comments.

Because you use positive numbers for deposit, and negative numbers for withdraw, the operation on initialAmount will be always the same: initialAmount + input (if negative, is will subtract from amount), so you can treat it like an one case in your code. In your code you use this line twice:

```
fromAcc_SameAcc.setInitiateAmount(fromAcc_SameAcc.getInitialAmount() + depOrWithAmount);
```

so you already could merge both cases into one, to avoid unnecessary repetitions. So only case when action will differ, is when there is not enough money on a account, you check it by:

```
if (depOrWithAmount - 1 < fromAcc_SameAcc.getInitialAmount())
```

but i think i will not work, because in withdraw operation `depOrWithAmount` is in negative numbers, so it will always be smaller than `fromAcc_SameAcc.getInitialAmount()`. You can use:

```
if (depOrWithAmount < 1 - fromAcc_SameAcc.getInitialAmount())
```

(but i think it is not too readable) or:

```
if (Math.abs(depOrWithAmount) > fromAcc_SameAcc.getInitialAmount()){}
```

to compare absolute value of input with initialAmout. However i used:

```
double result = edited.getInitialAmount() + input;
if(result < 0){...}
```

because it gives me `result` variable, which I can reuse if there is enough money, to gives new value to `initialAmount`. And if result is negative, it means that withdraw amount was bigger than initialAmount, so ther is no enough monay to withdraw.

I hope you found something useful in my post.

Comment: m.cekiera, thnaks, such a nice suggestion! I will follow your note. However, one question: why "if(result < 0)"? because we always compare the amount with the user input, so in this case it should be: if(input < 0). Or am I wrong?